# Why I am getting a lines under the table in phpmyadmin(localhost)

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to send a data from android studio, but I am getting lines under the table instead of assigning data.
Dont know where I am gone wrong.Plz help me.Thanks in advance.

[image]

This is my PHP code
add_employee

```
<?php
include('connection.php');                                                                  
if (isset($_POST["name"])){
    $emp_name = $_POST["name"];
    echo $emp_name;
    echo "is your name";
}
else{
    $emp_name = NULL;
    echo "POST filename is not assigned";
}

$success = 0;
$status = "Active";
$sqli = "INSERT INTO  `employee` (`emp_name`) VALUES ('$emp_name')";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqli)){
    $success=1;
}

$response["success"]=$success;
die(json_encode($response));
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Connection.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);    
if(!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($conn,'student');
?>
```

Comment: You've entered at least 24 NULL values. I'd suggest not inserting anything in the database unless you have a value.

Comment: Thanks!! I deleted the database twice and I again restarted so many times.Bad luck.It didnt work me.Is PHP code is correct??

Comment: Move your database calls inside of the IF statement, so you're only submitting the data if there's valid data to submit. I'd also say look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as you're wide open to SQL injection, and it also prevents quoting issues.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_POST["name"])`, it seems that there might be a problem with recieved data

Answer (score -1):

You have so many errors in your code. no db name, no proper query definition. you can use this simple code:

**Connection.php**

```
<?php 

 $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "slim";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
?>
```

Inserting employee code:

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST["name"])){
    $emp_name=$_POST["name"];
    echo $emp_name;
    echo "is your name";
 }
    else{
    $emp_name = null;
    echo "POST filename is not assigned";
    }

    $success=0;
    $status="Active";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO employee (name)
    VALUES ('$emp_name')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       $success=1;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

It's working and easy to understand for you.

Comment: You're concatenating wrong, and one of their issues is that they're passing in POST data when there may not be post data.

Comment: The most ideotic reason you've given to me. I've given the logic and Simplified solution. can't you copy the code of db connection in other file?

Comment: I removed my part of the comment about the connection, but the rest still stands.

Comment: Ok I Understand you need exact code to just copy paste.

Comment: I'm not the OP, so I don't need the code myself. However (1) You are concatenating the query string wrong. You only need the periods if you're breaking out of the quoted string. (That's ignoring that this would be open to SQL injection with the way the OP is trying to use the code). (2) The OP seems to be able to insert just fine, the issue is that they're inserting multiple null values, which means they need to check for valid data before inserting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152253/discussion-between-shahroze-nawaz-and-aynber).

Comment: So I just removed the backtics from table name and it works `$sqli = "INSERT INTO employee (name) 
VALUES ('$emp_name')";`

Comment: POST filename is not assigned
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\students\add_employee.php on line 19

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\students\add_employee.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\students\add_employee.php on line 19

Comment: I got these error when i used your code!!Anyway Thanks

Comment: include connection.php file that this error will not arise.